# Application Map# Create custom Map in azure portal?

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring, azure-log-analytics-workspace, azure-mapping-data-flow

is it possible create custom Application map path?

I have 100 + microservice and functions jobs and service bus and lots other components which connect to each other based on business flow.
I want to create my own business flow with specific components only rather then whole application map path. Any help..